# How do I get an Atheros AR8131 ethernet card working?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, atheros, ethernet

I have an Atheros AR8131 Ethernet card on a Lenovo b560 laptop. Sometime in the past, probably at some upgrade or other my *wired* connection stopped functioning. I know the card is ok because it works with windows.

I tried upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 hoping the problem would go away. It didn't...

Tried to google the problem, but all of the solutions I found didn't work for me.

This is probably a driver problem.

Any help will be appreciated. Please note that I'm a linux newbie so I don't really know what logs to post...

Niv

Answer (score 3):

I was having occasional drop-out issues with my Atheros AR8131 ethernet and found that an updated *alx* kernel driver was released by Qualcomm and works perfectly.

*Note: This alx driver will not be included in the kernel however the code will eventually find its way into the current atl1c kernel driver*.

[**alx Ethernet Driver**](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx)

- Remove current *atl1c* module and blacklist it:

  `rmmod atl1c`

  Add the line `blacklist atl1c` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`
- Download the [driver tarball](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx) and extract it.
- Install by executing these commands in the extracted driver directory:

  ```
  ./scripts/driver-select alx
  make
  sudo make install
  ```
- Verify module installed with:

  `lspci -v`

  ```
  Kernel driver in use: alx
  Kernel modules: alx
  ```

Comment: I am new here, so not sure how to do all the steps. I have removed atl1c and managed to blacklist it. I do not know how to do the next step. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you downloaded and extracted the code tar archive? The install commands would be run in the extracted code directory.

Comment: @Cas -- Thanks, alx got my AR8162 working! But it was not necessary to uninstall or blacklist atl1c. I just downloaded the driver tarball that you linked, installed alx per your instructions, and rebooted. I'm using ubuntu 12.04. Thanks again.

Comment: @Robert - extract a .tar.bz2 file with the command "tar -xjvf (filename)". A similar driver installation is spelled out in more detail at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9449490

Answer (score 2):

I'v made a HOW TO, step by step on this topic. Please look at:

http://tuxilero.blogspot.cz/2013/09/how-to-atheros-ar8162-linux-drivers.html

Hope it helps!